# Compute the probability to draw exactly $r$ balls from urn without repetition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need your help about my prob. problem. I have $n_1$ red balls and $n_2$ blue balls in the urn. Let $A$ be event that randomly draw $r$ balls from urn without repetition. I would like to find:

1. The prob. of even that draws $r_1 \ge k_1$ red balls from given the $r$ balls, where $0 \le k_1 \le n_1$
2. The prob. of even that draws $r_2 \ge k_2$ blue balls **and** $r_1 \ge k_1$ red balls from given the $r$ balls, where $0 \le k_1 \le n_1$,$0 \le k_2 \le n_2$
3. The prob. of even that draws $r_1 \ge k_1$ red balls **or** $r\ge k_1+k_2$ balls from given the $r$ balls, where $0 \le k_1 \le n_1$,$0 \le k_2 \le n_2$

Update: This is my solution that I tried

1. I draw $r$ balls. Define drawing $r_1 \ge k_1$ red balls as a success and otherwise as a failure. By using [Hypergeometric_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) we have

$$\begin{align}
P_1(x=r|r_1 \ge k_1) = \sum_{x=\max\{k_1,r-n_2\}}^{\min\{n_1,r\}} \frac{\binom{n_1}{x}\binom{n_2}{r-x}}{\binom{n}{r}}
\end{align}$$

Note that the range $x=\max\{...,r-n_2\}$ so that  $\binom{n_2}{r-x}$ is valid (as my understand)

2. I draw $r$ balls. Define drawing $r_1 \ge k_1$ red balls and $r_2 \ge k_2$ blue balls as a success and otherwise as a failure. By using [Hypergeometric_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) we have

????

I have no idea for part 2 and part 3. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Write down your thoughts and indicate the exact problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Yes, I will update now

Comment: I presume the balls are drawn with replacement?

Comment: No. it is without replacement.

Comment: @zhoraster: Could you help me?

Comment: For 2, remember that $r=r_1 + r_2$. So you get something similar to 1, but with a different upper limit of summation.

Comment: Could you put it in answer. I am very thankful to you if you can explain how to find the limit